# comprobar la existencia y el número de un proceso

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

tengo un problema con `multiprocessing`, necesito un código que genere 6 procesos (`multiprocessing.Process`), y como se pueden parar con el administrador de tareas, y haria todo irse al garete, necesito un programa (función (probablemente facilitada por `ctypes.windll` aunque no la halla encontrado),método o código) que compruebe el número de procesos hijos de uno en concreto que hay.
otro pequeño detalle, el código que se esta ejecutando no lo hace desde un archivo. Lo hace desde un `exec()`. Si necesitan codigo tampoco es mucho : solo es una función `WorkerB` que se encraga de comprobar eso (

```py
def WorkerB():
    pass #no tengo echo nada
```

) y un proceso de funciones definidas como `WorkerA`, siempre hijas de un WorkerB primero que es ejecutado, el código de `WorkerA` es tambien un simple pass por ahora.
NOTA : No uso `threading` por que el GIL bloquea `threads` "reales", es decir es paralelismo simulado. Y necesito paralelismo no simulado

Comment: En español, cual es tu error?

Comment: No se entiende qué necesitas exactamente o para qué. Si quieres saber cuántos hijos ha creado un cierto proceso ¿por qué no pones un contador en ese proceso que se incremente cada vez que crea uno? Si quieres en cambio numerar los hijos para que cada uno sepa "qué número es" ¿por qué no usas también un contador en el padre y se lo pasas como parámetro al hijo? Si es otra cosa la que necesitas, explica por favor para qué, pues quizás sea posible una solución sin necesidad de windll.

Comment: intentare añadir el contador, pero no se si tendre problemas a la hora de cancelar otro proceso desde un proceso externo

Comment: Para poder cancelar un proceso desde otro necesitas el pid del que quieres cancelar. En sistemas unix el pid del hijo es lo que `fork()` retorna al padre, pero aparentemente estás en Windows y en ese operativo los procesos se crean de otra forma. Tal vez tu pregunta debiera ser entonces "¿como averiguar el pid de un subproceso desde python en windows?" (no sé la respuesta)

Comment: tengo el pid, el problema no es ese. El problema es saber el número de procesos hijos de otro que se estan ejecutando

Comment: y lo de el contador no funciona, por que el modulo es <built-in> (esta ejecutado en ´exec()´, y de echo el código que se le pasa a el `exec` es un código extraido de un archivo encryptado,entonces ´pickle´ por algun motivo no puede serializarlo)

Comment: lo dieal seria algo en la API de windows que te devuelva los procesos hijos de otros. Parecido a lo que hace `TASKLIST` en windows

Comment: (si, tengo el proyecto en windows)